# Make header responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this responsive [website](http://conlami.org.mx/conlami/). But I have a problem I have been trying to solve. The problem is that header loses style when small screens

This is part of the code

```
    <div class="hgroup-wrap">
        <div id="container-header" class="container clearfix">
            <section id="site-logo" class="clearfix">
                  <h1 id="site-title">
                         <a href="http://conlami.org.mx/conlami/" title="CONLAMI" rel="home">
                              <img id="image-full" src="http://conlami.org.mx/conlami/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/LOGOTEXTO.png" alt="CONLAMI">
                         </a>
                  </h1>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This happens because header image is too large. Image is already responsive. But it doesn't work properly.

This wouldn't happen if for example I remove text from image and leave only logo.

I have tried text in another section but I couldn't make it work.

So. Do you have any suggestions about what can I try?

Comment: What do yo mean by header loses style ?

Comment: Your logo contains text also. Keep only the image for logo and text separately.

Comment: Not really. thanks for your  comment. I have tried that. But space and order in elements doesnt look good, That's why I include text in image. I will look up for a solution considering that

Comment: Use % for width instead of px.
`In media query, Normal (#site-logo  = 70% width  and #hgroup-right=30% width) 
in 'only screen and (max-width: 767px)'  ( (#site-logo  = 95% width  and .menu-toggle=5% width)) `

Then remove all fixed width.  It might be your solution.
Thanks